# Keep files in different folder with errors

Tags: android-studio

I have a basic question.

Sometimes I have files of code that is old, but I don't want to delete them from my project. I would like to bput them in a directly in the project folder in case I will need them. But they have errors in them, so my project doesn't run.

Is there any way that I can keep the files, even though they have errors? These files are not needed for the current running of the app, so the errors won't affect the app, I just want to keep the files for maybe later use.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the Folder from Build: To ensure that the errors in these files don't affect your project, you can exclude the folder from the build process. To do this:

Right-click on the "Unused" folder within Android Studio.
Select "Mark Directory as" > "Excluded."
This action tells Android Studio to ignore this folder during the build process, so any errors within it won't impact your app.